# The argument should be executed as a function inside the body in javascript

Tags: javascript

I create a function as a variable to print 'Welcome' to console. I want to execute that variable as a function inside another new function. How can I do that?

This is my first function:

```
var first = function() {
              console.log("Welcome");
            }
```

Comment: Could you post a pen to your code please?

Comment: please, show your code

Comment: The same way as you execute any other function: `first()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use it after it has been initialized:

```
var first = function() {
    console.log("Welcome");
}

var second = function() {
    first();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstFunction = function() {
    //Your code that what you want to do
}

var second = function() {
    firstFunction(); // calling first function
}
```